# Make same cluster

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['P1', 'C1'],
                    ['P2', 'C1'],
                    ['P2', 'C2'],
                    ['P3', 'C2']
                   ], columns=['id', 'cluster'])
```

In this data, the ids P1 and P2 belongs to same cluster C1 and ids P2 and P3 belongs to same cluster C2. However, since, P2 is common in both the clusters it indicates that P1, P2 and P3 belongs to same cluster.
How to make them to fall in the same cluster. Lets say H, so that the final result should be:

[Final dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqaPq.png)

I tried to map the same id and cluster to new id H, but didn't work